# AWS Lambda - NodeJS - nested Await / Async not returning

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Having this small Lambda-Function:

```
module.exports.handler = async( data , ctx, cb) => {
 console.log("start");
 createSth();
};


async function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
  console.log("in function: " + x);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function createSth() {
  var x = await resolveAfter2Seconds(10);
  console.log(x); // 10
}
```

I would have expted the following output

```
start
in function: 10
10
```

But I only get

```
start
in function: 10
```

So everything after `var x = await resolveAfter2Seconds(10);` is not executed.

It works outside of aws lambda in a similar setup.

Thanks.

Comment: What is timeout set for AWS lambda function

Comment: Did you need the `.then` on for `createSth().then()`? or an await: `await createSth()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `await` keyword while calling `createSth` function. This will allow main function to wait for the execution of the function and won't return

i.e.

```
module.exports.handler = async( data , ctx, cb) => {
    console.log("start");
    await createSth();
};
```